# Why PowerShell workflow is significantly slower than non-workflow script for XML file analysis

Tags: xml, performance, powershell

I am writing a PowerShell program to analyse the content of 1900+ big XML configuration files (50000+ lines, 1.5Mb). 
Just for test I move 36 test files to my PC (Win 10; PS 5.1; 32GB RAM) and write quick script to test the speed of execution.

```
$TestDir = "E:\Powershell\Test"
$TestXMLs = Get-ChildItem $TestDir -Recurse -Include *.xml

foreach ($TestXML in $TestXMLs)
{
    [xml]$XML = Get-Content $TestXML
    (($XML.root.servers.server).Where{$_.name -eq "Server1"}).serverid
}
```

That is completed for 36 to 40 seconds. I done several tests with measure-command.

Then I tried workflow with foreach -paralell assuming that parallel loading of several files will give me more faster process.

```
Workflow Test-WF
{
    $TestDir = "E:\Powershell\Test"
    $TestXMLs = Get-ChildItem $TestDir -Recurse -Include *.xml

    foreach -parallel -throttle 10 ($TestXML in $TestXMLs)
    {
        [xml]$XML = Get-Content $TestXML
        (($TestXML.root.servers.server).Where{$_.name -eq "Sevrver1"}).serverid
    }
}

Test-WF #execute workflow
```

Script with the workflow needs between 118 and 132 seconds.

Now I am just wondering what could be the reason that workflow works so much slower? Recompiling to XMAL maybe or slower algorithm for loading XML files in WWF?

Comment: BTW you can make the actual loading of XML several times faster: `$xml = [xml]''; $xml.Load($TestXML)`

Comment: Wow .... just test it between 818 and 889ms against 33s. 
I think that this just replace the need of workflow. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 18):

`foreach -parallel` is by far the slowest parallelization option you have with PowerShell, since Workflows are not designed for speed, but for long-running operations that can be safely interrupted and resumed.

The implementation of these safety mechanisms introduces some overhead, which is why your script is slower when run as a workflow.

If you want to optimize for execution speed, use runspaces instead:

```
$TestDir = "E:\Powershell\Test"
$TestXMLs = Get-ChildItem $TestDir -Recurse -Include *.xml

# Set up runspace pool
$RunspacePool = [runspacefactory]::CreateRunspacePool(1,10)
$RunspacePool.Open()

# Assign new jobs/runspaces to a variable
$Runspaces = foreach ($TestXML in $TestXMLs)
{
    # Create new PowerShell instance to hold the code to execute, add arguments
    $PSInstance = [powershell]::Create().AddScript({
        param($XMLPath)

        [xml]$XML = Get-Content $XMLPath
        (($XML.root.servers.server).Where{$_.name -eq "Server1"}).serverid
    }).AddParameter('XMLPath', $TestXML.FullName)

    # Assing PowerShell instance to RunspacePool
    $PSInstance.RunspacePool = $RunspacePool

    # Start executing asynchronously, keep instance + IAsyncResult objects
    New-Object psobject -Property @{
        Instance = $PSInstance
        IAResult = $PSInstance.BeginInvoke()
        Argument = $TestXML
    }
}

# Wait for the the runspace jobs to complete
while($Runspaces |Where-Object{-not $_.IAResult.IsCompleted})
{
    Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 500
}

# Collect the results
$Results = $Runspaces |ForEach-Object {
    $Output = $_.Instance.EndInvoke($_.IAResult)
    New-Object psobject -Property @{
        File = $TestXML
        ServerID = $Output
    }
}
```

---

#### Fast XML processing bonus tips:

As [wOxxOm suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41796959/why-powershell-workflow-is-significantly-slower-than-non-workflow-script-for-xml#comment70782576_41796959), using `Xml.Load()` is way faster than using `Get-Content` to read in the XML document.

Furthermore, using dot notation (`$xml.root.servers.server`) and the `Where({})` extension method is also going to be painfully slow if there are many `servers` or `server` nodes. Use the `SelectNodes()` method with an XPath expression to search for "Server1" instead (be aware that XPath is case-sensitive):

```
$PSInstance = [powershell]::Create().AddScript({
    param($XMLPath)

    $XML = New-Object Xml
    $XML.Load($XMLPath)
    $Server1Node = $XML.SelectNodes('/root/servers/server[@name = "Server1"]')
    return $Server1Node.serverid
}).AddParameter('XMLPath', $TestXML.FullName)
```

Comment: Actually I need to get 15 or more element values from every xml + file path etc. and export them into csv for analysis and records. 
But will test your solution as well. Thanks you very much.

Comment: @autosvet You can still do that using the above approach, just edit the scriptblock inside `AddScript()` accordingly. Export the `$Results` variable to CSV when done

Comment: Yep. I will try because I am curious to see difference in times. Thanks again.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen: I tried to generalize your code, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52975186/how-to-pass-psitem-in-a-scriptblock .