# How to pass $_ ($PSItem) in a ScriptBlock

Tags: powershell, foreach, parallel-processing, pipe, powershell-sdk

I'm basically building my own parallel foreach pipeline function, using runspaces.

My problem is: I call my function like this:

```
somePipeline | MyNewForeachFunction { scriptBlockHere } | pipelineGoesOn...
```

How can I pass the `$_` parameter correctly into the ScriptBlock? It works when the ScriptBlock contains as first line

```
param($_)
```

But as you might have noticed, the powershell built-in ForEach-Object and Where-Object do **not** need such a parameter declaration in every ScriptBlock that is passed to them.

Thanks for your answers in advance
fjf2002

**EDIT:**

The goal is: I want comfort for the users of function `MyNewForeachFunction` - they shoudln't need to write a line `param($_)` in their script blocks.

Inside `MyNewForeachFunction`, The ScriptBlock is currently called via

```
$PSInstance = [powershell]::Create().AddScript($ScriptBlock).AddParameter('_', $_)
$PSInstance.BeginInvoke()
```

**EDIT2:**

The point is, how does for example the implementation of the built-in function `ForEach-Object` achieve that `$_` need't be declared as a parameter in its ScriptBlock parameter, and can I use that functionality, too?

(If the answer is, `ForEach-Object` is a built-in function and uses some magic I can't use, then this would disqualify the language PowerShell as a whole in my opinion)

**EDIT3:**

Thanks to mklement0, I could finally build my general foreach loop. Here's the code:

```
function ForEachParallel {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory)] [ScriptBlock] $ScriptBlock,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)] [int] $PoolSize = 20,
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline)] $PipelineObject
    )

    Begin {
        $RunspacePool = [runspacefactory]::CreateRunspacePool(1, $poolSize)
        $RunspacePool.Open()
        $Runspaces = @()
    }

    Process {
        $PSInstance = [powershell]::Create().
            AddCommand('Set-Variable').AddParameter('Name', '_').AddParameter('Value', $PipelineObject).
            AddCommand('Set-Variable').AddParameter('Name', 'ErrorActionPreference').AddParameter('Value', 'Stop').
            AddScript($ScriptBlock)

        $PSInstance.RunspacePool = $RunspacePool

        $Runspaces += New-Object PSObject -Property @{
            Instance = $PSInstance
            IAResult = $PSInstance.BeginInvoke()
            Argument = $PipelineObject
        }
    }

    End {
        while($True) {
            $completedRunspaces = @($Runspaces | where {$_.IAResult.IsCompleted})

            $completedRunspaces | foreach {
                Write-Output $_.Instance.EndInvoke($_.IAResult)
                $_.Instance.Dispose()
            }

            if($completedRunspaces.Count -eq $Runspaces.Count) {
                break
            }

            $Runspaces = @($Runspaces | where { $completedRunspaces -notcontains $_ })
            Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 250
        }

        $RunspacePool.Close()
        $RunspacePool.Dispose()
    }
}
```

Code partly from MathiasR.Jessen, [Why PowerShell workflow is significantly slower than non-workflow script for XML file analysis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41796959/why-powershell-workflow-is-significantly-slower-than-non-workflow-script-for-xml)

Comment: Either inspect the AST of the scriptblock and inject a param declaration if none exist, or extend PSCmdlet and invoke the scriptblock with the dollarUnderscore parameter set

Comment: The first argument passed to your scriptblock is in `$args[0]` or if it's taken as pipeline: `$input`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen: Could you be more specific? Do ForEach-Object / Where-Object etc. also do it like this?

Comment: @mklement0: Thanks, I've added Dispose calls, a sane ErrorActionPreference and I have removed the "barrier" - now completed results get passed down the pipeline *before* all runspaces have finished.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The key is to define `$_` as a *variable* that your script block can see, via a call to `Set-Variable`.

Here's a simple example:

```
function MyNewForeachFunction {
  [CmdletBinding()]
  param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory)]
    [scriptblock] $ScriptBlock
    ,
    [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline)]
    $InputObject
  )

  process {
    $PSInstance = [powershell]::Create()

    # Add a call to define $_ based on the current pipeline input object
    $null = $PSInstance.
      AddCommand('Set-Variable').
        AddParameter('Name', '_').
        AddParameter('Value', $InputObject).
      AddScript($ScriptBlock)

    $PSInstance.Invoke()
  }

}

# Invoke with sample values.
1, (Get-Date) | MyNewForeachFunction { "[$_]" }
```

The above yields something like:

```
[1]
[10/26/2018 00:17:37]
```

Answer (score 4):

What I think you're looking for (and what I was looking for) is to support a ["delay-bind" script block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_script_blocks?view=powershell-5.1#using-delay-bind-script-blocks-with-parameters), supported in PowerShell 5.1+. The documentation tells a bit about what's required, but doesn't currently provide any user-script examples.

### Tough Technical Option: Manual Implementation

The gist of the documentation is that PowerShell will *implicitly* detect that your function can accept a delay-bind script block if it defines an explicitly typed pipeline parameter (either `by Value` or `by PropertyName`), as long as it's not of type `[scriptblock]` or type `[object]`.

```
function Test-DelayedBinding {
     param(
         # this is our typed pipeline parameter
         # per doc this cannot be of type [scriptblock] or [object],
         # but testing shows that type [object] may be permitted
         [AllowEmptyString()]
         [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline)][string[]]$String,
         # this is our scriptblock parameter
         [Parameter(Position=0)][scriptblock]$Filter
     )

     Process {
         foreach($s in $String) {
             if (&$filter $s) {
                 Write-Output $s
             }
         }
     }
 }


# sample invocation
>'foo', 'fi', 'foofoo', 'fib' | Test-DelayedBinding { return $_ -match 'foo' }
foo
foofoo
```

Note that the delay-bind is subject to the following limitations:

- delay-bind will only be applied if input is piped into the function
- scoping and closure do not get applied in the same way as for built-in delay-bind cmdlets

The frustrating part is that there is no way to explicitly specify that delay-bind should be used, and errors resulting from incorrectly structuring your function may be non-obvious.

### Easier Alternative: Using Built-In Cmdlets

PowerShell provides built-in cmdlets that implement delayed binding for both iteration/transformation (`ForEach-Object`) and filtering (`Where-Object`), which covers most situations where you'd want to use delay-bind.

Use these to easily build a custom delay-bind function without the above listed limitations:

```
function Test-WhereBasedFilter {
    param(
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline)]
        [object[]]
        $Object,

        [Parameter(Mandatory,Position=0)]
        [scriptblock]
        $Filter
    )

    process {
        foreach ($o in $object) {
            $o | Where-Object $Filter | Write-Output
        }
    }
}

# sample invocation
> 'foo', 'fi', 'foofoo', '', $null, 'fib' | Test-WhereBasedFilter { return $_ -match 'foo' }
foo
foofoo


function Test-ForBasedIterator {
    param(
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline)]
        [object[]]
        $Object,

        [Parameter(Mandatory,Position=0)]
        [scriptblock]
        $ScriptBlock
    )

    process {
        foreach ($o in $object) {
            $o | ForEach-Object $ScriptBlock | Write-Output
        }
    }
}

# sample invocation
> 'foo', 'fi', 'foofoo', '', $null, 'fib' | Test-ForBasedIterator { " 
 $_  foo!" }
  foo  foo!
  fi  foo!
  foofoo  foo!
    foo!
  fib  foo!
```

Building a custom delay-bind around built-ins is quicker and adds functionality:

- input can be passed as a standard parameter as well as through pipeline
- object inputs work fine
- scoping and closures are handled as per the built-in you're using (which is more likely to be the user's expectation)

Comment: This should probably be the accepted answer now. This worked for me

Comment: @Sled - I've updated the answer to include an easier/better option I've discovered since original post, and to clarify further. Also converted pipeline param to be non-mandatory so it can accept null/empty.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`ScriptBlock.InvokeWithContext` Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.scriptblock.invokewithcontext?view=powershellsdk-7.2.0) to pass the input object as `$_` (`$PSItem`) to your [`powershell`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.powershell?view=powershellsdk-7.3.0) instances. It's also worth noting, seeing the last edit from your question, **you should definitely add an [`Ast.GetScriptBlock()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.language.scriptblockast.getscriptblock?view=powershellsdk-7.3.0#system-management-automation-language-scriptblockast-getscriptblock) to the `scriptblock` argument to strip out its runspace affinity** otherwise you will run into issues, either crashing your session or deadlocks. See [**GitHub issue #4003**](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/4003) for in depth details.

If you're looking for a more advanced version of your function, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74257557/15339544) or a more advanced version in the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/santisq/PSParallelPipeline) which does not use a [`runspacepool`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.runspaces.runspacepool?view=powershellsdk-7.3.0).

```bash
function MyNewForeachFunction {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline)]
        [psobject] $PipelineObject,

        [Parameter(Mandatory, Position = 0)]
        [scriptblock] $ScriptBlock
    )

    process {
        try {
            # `.Ast.GetScriptBlock()` Needed to avoid runspace affinity issues!
            $ps = [powershell]::Create().AddScript({
                param([scriptblock] $sb, [psobject] $inp)

                $sb.InvokeWithContext($null, [psvariable]::new('_', $inp))
            }).AddParameters(@{
                sb  = $ScriptBlock.Ast.GetScriptBlock()
                inp = $PipelineObject
            })
            
            # using `.Invoke()` for demo purposes, would use `.BeginInvoke()`
            # instead for multi-threading
            $ps.Invoke()

            if ($ps.HadErrors) {
                foreach ($e in $ps.Streams.Error) {
                    $PSCmdlet.WriteError($e)
                }
            }
        }
        finally {
            if ($ps) {
                $ps.Dispose()
            }
        }
    }
}

0..10 | MyNewForeachFunction { $_ }
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this can help.
I'd normally run auto-generated jobs in parallel this way:

```
Get-Job | Remove-Job

foreach ($param in @(3,4,5)) {

 Start-Job  -ScriptBlock {param($lag); sleep $lag; Write-Output "slept for $lag seconds" } -ArgumentList @($param)

}

Get-Job | Wait-Job | Receive-Job
```

If I understand you correctly, you are trying to get rid of param() inside the scriptblock. You may try to wrap that SB with another one. Below is the workaround for my sample:

```
Get-Job | Remove-Job

#scriptblock with no parameter
$job = { sleep $lag; Write-Output "slept for $lag seconds" }

foreach ($param in @(3,4,5)) {

 Start-Job  -ScriptBlock {param($param, $job)
  $lag = $param
  $script = [string]$job
  Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock ([Scriptblock]::Create($script))
 } -ArgumentList @($param, $job)

}

Get-Job | Wait-Job | Receive-Job
```

Answer (score 1):

```
# I was looking for an easy way to do this in a scripted function,
# and the below worked for me in PSVersion 5.1.17134.590

function Test-ScriptBlock {
    param(
        [string]$Value,
        [ScriptBlock]$FilterScript={$_}
    )
    $_ = $Value
    & $FilterScript
}
Test-ScriptBlock -Value 'unimportant/long/path/to/foo.bar' -FilterScript { [Regex]::Replace($_,'unimportant/','') }
```