# Is there an easier way to run commands in parallel while keeping it efficient in Windows PowerShell?

Tags: multithreading, powershell, concurrency, parallel-processing, runspace

This self-answer intends to provide an easy and efficient parallelism alternative for those stuck with Windows PowerShell and being unable to install Modules due to, for example, Company Policies.

In Windows PowerShell, the *built-in* available alternatives for **local** parallel invocations are [`Start-Job`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/start-job?view=powershell-7.2) and [`workflow`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/psworkflow/about/about_workflows?view=powershell-5.1), both known to be very slow, inefficient, and one of them (`workflow`) is not even recommended to use and no longer available in [newer versions of PowerShell](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell).

The other alternative is to rely on the [PowerShell SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/windows-powershell?view=powershell-7.2) and code our own parallel logic using what the [`System.Management.Automation.Runspaces` Namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.runspaces?view=powershellsdk-7.0.0) has to offer. This is definitively the most efficient approach and is what [`ForEach-Object -Parallel`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object?view=powershell-7.2#-parallel) (in PowerShell Core) as well as the [`Start-ThreadJob`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/threadjob/start-threadjob?view=powershell-7.2) (preinstalled in PowerShell Core and available in Windows PowerShell through the [PowerShell Gallery](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ThreadJob/2.0.0)) uses behind the scenes.

A simple example:

```bash
$throttlelimit = 3

$pool = [runspacefactory]::CreateRunspacePool(1, $throttlelimit)
$pool.Open()

$tasks = 0..10 | ForEach-Object {
    $ps = [powershell]::Create().AddScript({
        'hello world from {0}' -f [runspace]::DefaultRunspace.InstanceId
        Start-Sleep 3
    })
    $ps.RunspacePool = $pool

    @{ Instance = $ps; AsyncResult = $ps.BeginInvoke() }
}

$tasks | ForEach-Object {
    $_.Instance.EndInvoke($_.AsyncResult)
}

$tasks.Instance, $pool | ForEach-Object Dispose
```

This is great but gets tedious and often times complicated when the code has more complexity and in consequence brings lots of questions.

Is there an easier way to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**NOTE**

Further updates to this function will be published to the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/santisq/PSParallelPipeline) as well as to the [PowerShell Gallery](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/PSParallelPipeline/). The code in this answer **will no longer be maintained**.

The documentation for the function as well as usage examples can be found [**here**](https://github.com/santisq/PSParallelPipeline/blob/main/docs/en-US/Invoke-Parallel.md). Note that the Module version no longer has a `-ThreadOptions` parameter and implements `-UseNewRunspace` and `-TimeoutSeconds` parameters however its usage should be the same.

Contributions are more than welcome, if you wish to contribute, fork the repo and submit a pull request with the changes.

---

Since this is a topic that can be confusing and often brings questions to the site I have decided to create this function that can simplify this tedious task and help those stuck in Windows PowerShell. The aim is to have it as simple and as friendly as possible, it should also be a function that could be copy-pasted in our [`$PROFILE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7.2#profile) to be reused whenever needed and not require the installation of a Module (as stated in the question).

This function has been greatly inspired by RamblingCookieMonster's [`Invoke-Parallel`](https://github.com/RamblingCookieMonster/Invoke-Parallel) and Boe Prox's [`PoshRSJob`](https://github.com/proxb/PoshRSJob) and is merely a simplified take on those with a few improvements.

#### DEFINITION

```bash
using namespace System.Collections
using namespace System.Collections.Generic
using namespace System.Management.Automation
using namespace System.Management.Automation.Language
using namespace System.Management.Automation.Runspaces
using namespace System.Threading
using namespace System.Text

# The function must run in the scope of a Module.
# `New-Module` must be used for portability. Otherwise store the
# function in a `.psm1` and import it via `Import-Module`.
New-Module PSParallelPipeline -ScriptBlock {
    class CommandCompleter : IArgumentCompleter {
        [IEnumerable[CompletionResult]] CompleteArgument(
            [string] $commandName,
            [string] $parameterName,
            [string] $wordToComplete,
            [CommandAst] $commandAst,
            [IDictionary] $fakeBoundParameters) {

            return [CompletionCompleters]::CompleteCommand(
                $wordToComplete,
                [NullString]::Value,
                [CommandTypes]::Function)
        }
    }

    function Invoke-Parallel {
        [CmdletBinding(PositionalBinding = $false)]
        [Alias('parallel')]
        param(
            [Parameter(Mandatory, ValueFromPipeline)]
            [object] $InputObject,

            [Parameter(Mandatory, Position = 0)]
            [scriptblock] $ScriptBlock,

            [Parameter()]
            [ValidateRange(1, 63)]
            [int] $ThrottleLimit = 5,

            [Parameter()]
            [hashtable] $Variables,

            [Parameter()]
            [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
            [ArgumentCompleter([CommandCompleter])]
            [string[]] $Functions,

            [Parameter()]
            [ValidateSet('ReuseThread', 'UseNewThread')]
            [PSThreadOptions] $ThreadOptions = [PSThreadOptions]::ReuseThread
        )

        begin {
            try {
                $iss = [initialsessionstate]::CreateDefault2()

                foreach ($key in $Variables.PSBase.Keys) {
                    if ($Variables[$key] -is [scriptblock]) {
                        $PSCmdlet.ThrowTerminatingError([ErrorRecord]::new(
                            [PSArgumentException]::new('Passed-in script block variables are not supported.'),
                            'VariableCannotBeScriptBlock',
                            [ErrorCategory]::InvalidType,
                            $Variables[$key]))
                    }

                    $iss.Variables.Add([SessionStateVariableEntry]::new($key, $Variables[$key], ''))
                }

                foreach ($function in $Functions) {
                    $def = (Get-Command $function).Definition
                    $iss.Commands.Add([SessionStateFunctionEntry]::new($function, $def))
                }

                $usingParams = @{}
                foreach ($usingstatement in $ScriptBlock.Ast.FindAll({ $args[0] -is [UsingExpressionAst] }, $true)) {
                    $variableAst = [UsingExpressionAst]::ExtractUsingVariable($usingstatement)
                    $varPath = $variableAst.VariablePath.UserPath
                    $varText = $usingstatement.ToString()

                    if ($usingstatement.SubExpression -is [VariableExpressionAst]) {
                        $varText = $varText.ToLowerInvariant()
                    }

                    $key = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes($varText))

                    if ($usingParams.ContainsKey($key)) {
                        continue
                    }

                    $value = $PSCmdlet.SessionState.PSVariable.GetValue($varPath)

                    if ($value -is [scriptblock]) {
                        $PSCmdlet.ThrowTerminatingError([ErrorRecord]::new(
                            [PSArgumentException]::new('Passed-in script block variables are not supported.'),
                            'VariableCannotBeScriptBlock',
                            [ErrorCategory]::InvalidType,
                            $value))
                    }

                    if ($usingstatement.SubExpression -isnot [VariableExpressionAst]) {
                        [Stack[Ast]] $subexpressionStack = $usingstatement.SubExpression.FindAll({
                            $args[0] -is [IndexExpressionAst] -or
                            $args[0] -is [MemberExpressionAst] },
                            $false)

                        while ($subexpressionStack.Count) {
                            $subexpression = $subexpressionStack.Pop()
                            if ($subexpression -is [IndexExpressionAst]) {
                                $idx = $subexpression.Index.SafeGetValue()
                                $value = $value[$idx]
                                continue
                            }

                            if ($subexpression -is [MemberExpressionAst]) {
                                $member = $subexpression.Member.SafeGetValue()
                                $value = $value.$member
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    $usingParams.Add($key, $value)
                }

                $pool = [runspacefactory]::CreateRunspacePool(1, $ThrottleLimit, $iss, $Host)
                $tasks = [List[hashtable]]::new()
                $pool.ThreadOptions = $ThreadOptions
                $pool.Open()
            }
            catch {
                $PSCmdlet.ThrowTerminatingError($_)
            }
        }
        process {
            try {
                # Thanks to Patrick Meinecke for his help here.
                # https://github.com/SeeminglyScience/
                $ps = [powershell]::Create().
                    AddScript({ $args[0].InvokeWithContext($null, [psvariable]::new('_', $args[1])) }).
                    AddArgument($ScriptBlock.Ast.GetScriptBlock()).
                    AddArgument($InputObject)

                # This is how `Start-Job` does it's magic.
                # Thanks to Jordan Borean for his help here.
                # https://github.com/jborean93
                if ($usingParams.Count) {
                    $null = $ps.AddParameters(@{ '--%' = $usingParams })
                }

                $ps.RunspacePool = $pool

                $tasks.Add(@{
                    Instance    = $ps
                    AsyncResult = $ps.BeginInvoke()
                })
            }
            catch {
                $PSCmdlet.WriteError($_)
            }
        }
        end {
            try {
                while ($tasks.Count) {
                    $id = [WaitHandle]::WaitAny($tasks.AsyncResult.AsyncWaitHandle, 200)

                    if ($id -eq [WaitHandle]::WaitTimeout) {
                        continue
                    }

                    $task = $tasks[$id]
                    $task.Instance.EndInvoke($task.AsyncResult)

                    foreach ($err in $task.Instance.Streams.Error) {
                        $PSCmdlet.WriteError($err)
                    }

                    $tasks.RemoveAt($id)
                }
            }
            catch {
                $PSCmdlet.WriteError($_)
            }
            finally {
                foreach ($task in $tasks.Instance) {
                    if ($task -is [IDisposable]) {
                        $task.Dispose()
                    }
                }

                if ($pool -is [IDisposable]) {
                    $pool.Dispose()
                }
            }
        }
    }
} -Function Invoke-Parallel | Import-Module -Force
```

Answer (score -2):

PowerShell workflows provide a powerful way to run PowerShell modules and scripts against multiple servers in parallel. There are a lot of different ways in PowerShell to run scripts against multiple instances, but most methods simply run serially one server at a time.

Comment: I think you missed the premise of the question. This question is about running local parallel invocations, has nothing to do with remote servers. Leaving that aside, `workflow` is awfully inefficient and not even recommended.