# PowerShell pipeline conveyer. Set throttle limit

Tags: powershell, parallel-processing, pipeline, powershell-5.1

It looks like this code is executing in parallel. There are many machines in the domain. I would like to finetune how many requests do in the same time for a sake of speed. How can set a throttle limit?

```
$comps = Get-ADComputer * -Properties description
$comps `
    | Select Name,
        @{name="User"; e={
            (Get-WMIObject -Class Win32_ComputerSystem -Computer $_.name).Username}},
        @{name="Description"; e={
            ($_.description)}} `
    | Out-GridView
```

Comment: [`$comps | Foreach-Object -Parallel -TrottleLimit { ...`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object)?

Comment: @iRon We've got Windows 10 with Powershell 5.1. Such command doesn't exist I think.

Comment: Probably the easiest (and fastest) solution is [installing a newer version of PowerShell](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell) which runs aside the existing Windows PowerShell.

Comment: See also the solution from **[@Santiago Squarzon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15339544/santiago-squarzon)** in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/q/74257556/1701026