# Eventhandling of Forms-timer and System-timer in powershell

Tags: .net, powershell, winforms, timer

I read that Timers.timer is a wrapper for the Threading.timer class. The timer should run on a workerthread of the threadpool. Yet in below example, the event isn't executed when the dialog is shown. I should guess that the form-thread and the worker thread are running independently and so the file would be filled with different values? Now they are the same because all fired events are executed just after the form is closed.

```
$timer = New-Object Timers.timer
$frm = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$timer.Interval = 2000
Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $timer -EventName Elapsed -Action {get-date -Format "ss" >> dezefile.txt}
$timer.Start()
$frm.ShowDialog()
$timer.stop()
$timer.Dispose()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- The **PowerShell engine can only process events registered for via [`Register-ObjectEvent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/register-objectevent) *while it is in control of the foreground thread***.
- **A [`.ShowDialog()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Windows.Forms.Form.ShowDialog) call puts [WinForms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/overview/) in charge of the foreground thread, blocking PowerShell's event processing** until after the form (dialog) is closed.

**Solution options:**

- Use a [`System.Windows.Forms.Timer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.timer) instance instead, and subscribe to its `Tick` event via an `add_Tick()` call, and perform the desired processing inside the script block passed to the call.
- Forgo a `.ShowDialog()` call in favor of a non-blocking `.Show()` call, which requires subsequently entering a loop with periodic `[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::DoEvents()` calls.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68120135/45375) for details.

Answer (score 0):

The timer does work with following modification to your code.  I added the using statement, full path of the Namespaces and changed the filename of output.

```
using assembly System.Windows.Forms

$timer = New-Object System.Timers.timer
$frm = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$timer.Interval = 2000
Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $timer -EventName Elapsed -Action {get-date -Format "ss" >> c:\temp\test.txt}
$timer.Start()
$frm.ShowDialog()
$timer.stop()
$timer.Dispose()
```